# How do I monitor pyusb events in the background on a windows machine

Tags: python, winapi, windows-services, pywin32, pyusb

I have a PyUSB+PyQt script working on windows interfacing with a USB printer. I want to respond to printer connect/disconnect events.

I am unsure on how to write the event loop to keep monitoring the USB port. I will also have some processing going on in my main program, so should this be running in a separate thread.

Could someone help with the best practice to build this kind of a PyUSB functionality ?